# inconsistent results when reading the memory of another process with winapi ReadProcessMemory

Tags: winapi, rust

So following on with my attempt at making a memory scanner in rust, I've stumbled upon some problems with the output of the reading script. It seems that sometimes the returned array of u8 is large and mostly zeroed out with some values here and there. It looks akin to the output from second episode of [this tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRPMdb1YMS8). Most frequently however it seems to find no memory at all, returning 0 from ReadProcessMemory with invalid handle error. Sometime however it does neither and keep on returning few small identical looking regions (always the same).

Below is my script narrowed down to be very basic:

```rust
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::iter::once;
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::mem::size_of;
use winapi::ctypes::c_void;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::DWORD;
use winapi::shared::ntdef::HANDLE;
use winapi::um::memoryapi::{ReadProcessMemory, VirtualQueryEx};
use winapi::um::processthreadsapi::OpenProcess;
use winapi::um::winnt::{MEM_COMMIT, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, PAGE_READWRITE, PAGE_WRITECOPY, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, PROCESS_VM_READ, PROCESS_VM_WRITE, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS};
use winapi::um::winuser::{FindWindowW, GetWindowThreadProcessId};
use winapi::_core::ptr::null_mut;
use winapi::shared::windef::HWND;
use winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError;

pub const RW_FLAGS: DWORD = PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY | PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE;
pub const ACCESS_PERMS: DWORD = PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE;



// a static function to get wide string from &str
pub fn win32_string(value: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    OsStr::new(value).encode_wide().chain(once(0)).collect()
}

pub unsafe fn read_from_pid(pid: u32) {
    let handle: HANDLE = OpenProcess(ACCESS_PERMS,
                                     0, pid);
    // OpenProcess -> HANDLE -> *mut c_void ( a mutable pointer to anything )
    println!("hProc: {:?}",handle);

    let mut current: *const _ = 0_usize as *const _;
    // is a pointer sized int we treat as pointer, not a pointer to pointer sized int we treat as pointer to c_void!

    let mut meminfo = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION::default();
    // memory basic information ( mutable to be populated from structs )


    let mut bytes_read: usize = 0;
    // was read per read

    let mut buff: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    // temporary vector for displaying the contents

    while VirtualQueryEx(handle, current,
                         &mut meminfo, size_of::<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>()) != 0 {

        if meminfo.State & MEM_COMMIT != 0 && meminfo.Protect & RW_FLAGS != 0 {
            // if memory was written to by an app and has the permissions to access it then


            let outcome_of_read = ReadProcessMemory(handle,
                                                    meminfo.BaseAddress,
                                                    buff.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void,
                                                    meminfo.RegionSize,
                                                    &mut bytes_read);

            if outcome_of_read == 0 {
                // if zero then nothing was read -> reached the end of process memory
                println!("no mem");
                println!("has error: {:?}",GetLastError());
                break;
            } else {
                // if not zero then set len to bytes read
                // cuz u8 = 1 byte = unsigned c_char
                buff.set_len(bytes_read);
                println!("have buff: {:?}", buff);
            }
        }

        current = (current as usize + meminfo.RegionSize) as *mut _;
        // keep on adding size of chunks read
    }
}



fn main() {
    unsafe {

        let winname: Vec<u16> = win32_string("Test App");
        // wide string

        let hwnd: HWND = FindWindowW(null_mut(),winname.as_ptr());
        // getting window handle

        println!("HWND: {:?}",hwnd);

        if !hwnd.is_null() {
            // if valid window handle

            let mut pid: DWORD = DWORD::default();
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&mut pid);
            // get pid for window handle

            println!("pid: {:?}",pid);
            read_from_pid(pid);

        }

    }
}
```

and further down is my test app (written with druid crate):

```rust
use druid::widget::{Align, Flex, Label, TextBox, Button};
use druid::{AppLauncher, Data, Env, Lens, LocalizedString, Widget, WindowDesc, WidgetExt};

const WINDOW_TITLE: LocalizedString<AppState> = LocalizedString::new("Test App");

#[derive(Clone, Data, Lens)]
struct AppState {
    num: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let main_window = WindowDesc::new(build_root_widget)
        .title(WINDOW_TITLE)
        .window_size((400.0, 400.0));

    let initial_state = AppState {
        num: 255_u64,
    };

    AppLauncher::with_window(main_window)
        .launch(initial_state)
        .expect("Failed to launch application");
}

fn build_root_widget() -> impl Widget<AppState> {

    let button = Button::dynamic(|data: &AppState,_env| -> String {format!("has number {:?}",data.num)})
        .on_click(|_ctx, data: &mut AppState, _env| {
        data.num += 1;
    });

    let layout = Flex::column().with_child(button);
    Align::centered(layout)
}
```

My suspicion that i need to close the hProc handle somehow, but since there is no CloseProcess function from what i can see I'm not sure if that's the cause of the problem. Despite that I tried to call CLoseHandle on my hProc after the read to no avail sadly.

I've also ensured it acquires the correct pid by comparing it to the entry from Task Manager.

**update:**
According to the comment from Inspectable I looked into the question of permissions (and currently looking into the nature of virtual memory). I've tried to copy [this example function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-privilege) in my rust code like so:

```rust
pub unsafe fn set_perms(hToken: HANDLE, privilege: Vec<u16>, enable: bool) -> bool {
    let mut luid: LUID = LUID::default();
    let mut outcome: bool = false;

    if LookupPrivilegeValueW(null_mut(), privilege.as_ptr(), &mut luid).is_positive() {
        let mut tp: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES = TOKEN_PRIVILEGES::default();

        tp.PrivilegeCount += 1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = if enable {SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED} else {0};

        if AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE,
                                 &mut tp, 0,
                                 null_mut(), null_mut()).is_positive() {
            outcome = (GetLastError() == 0);
        }
    }


    outcome
}


pub unsafe fn get_debug_for_current_proc() -> bool {
    let mut hProc: HANDLE = GetCurrentProcess();
    let mut hToken: HANDLE = null_mut();
    let mut priv_name: Vec<u16> = win32_string(SE_DEBUG_NAME);

    OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &mut hToken);
    let ret = set_perms(hToken, priv_name, true);
    CloseHandle(hProc);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    ret
}
```

It seem to work, however the problem persists.

Comment: Your suspicion is wrong, just as the assumptions. The assumption is that a live process wouldn't change its internal state over time. You will have to fix that assumption before you can hope to make any forward progress.

Comment: I'm fully aware that process dont maintain exatly same memory values and layout as they run. But i doubt that at any point process can have no memeory, or change their memory layout so significantly like switching from 1 large segment to 3 tiny ones without much happening in the process. Unless i miss something like under the hood druid magic or some windows specifics that is.

Comment: **All** of your assumptions are off. Like, literally all. The return value of `OpenProcess` has a meaning, but you aren't checking it to determine success or failure. `PROCESS_VM_READ` and `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` require that the caller has special permissions, but you aren't establishing those. You are assuming that virtual memory were used by processes directly. It isn't. It merely provides the building blocks for higher-level heap implementations. Observing large regions of zeroed memory is to be expected. Start [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-management).